Treetable Primeng issue using direction RTL
image for example
Treetable Primeng issue using direction RTL when you scroll right and left header not scrolling
Can You Help us in github repo Or Online editors
Iam know Primeng not support RTL
iam adding direction: rtl; on body

Please post the HTML as text, not a screenshot.

You are not using PrimeFaces / JSF

Iam edit on this function with name onBodyScroll(event) and et my selected language from local storage
You can choose an other way by direction value this is path file edit
this is file path to edit node_modules/primeng/fesm2022/primeng-treetable.mjs
This is My code use for this sollution in function


onBodyScroll(event) {
        if (this.preventBodyScrollPropagation) {
            this.preventBodyScrollPropagation = false;
            return;
        }
        if (this.scrollHeaderViewChild && this.scrollHeaderViewChild.nativeElement) {
            let lang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lang'))['code'] || 'en'
            if(lang == 'ar'){
                this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = 'unset'
                this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginRight = event.target.scrollLeft + 'px';
            }else{
                this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginRight = 'unset'
                this.scrollHeaderBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = -1 * event.target.scrollLeft + 'px';
            }
        }
        if (this.scrollFooterViewChild && this.scrollFooterViewChild.nativeElement) {
            this.scrollFooterBoxViewChild.nativeElement.style.marginLeft = -1 * event.target.scrollLeft + 'px';
        }
        if (this.frozenSiblingBody) {
            this.frozenSiblingBody.scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
        }
    }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.min.js"></script>




  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.isRtl) {
        this.applyStyle();
        const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('p-treetable-scrollable-body');
        if (elements.length > 0) {
          const element = elements[1] as HTMLElement;
          element.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
        } else {
          console.log('Element not found');
        }
      }

    }, 500);

  }

  applyStyle() {
    if (this.isRtl) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        $(".p-treetable-scrollable-view").css('left', '0px');
        $(".p-treetable-scrollable-header-box").css('padding-right', "0px");
        $(".p-treetable .p-treetable-tbody > tr > td").css('text-align', 
        'unset');
        $("chevronrighticon").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
      }, 10);
    }

  }
try this code and it will work with you with out any problem , isolve this issue with this steps 

